# PHP - Simple Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

Consider the below code

```
$t = preg_replace('/0+$/','',".800000000000000"); //Replace last 0s
```

This gives me output as .8 as expected

Now consider the below code

```
$a = .80;
$t = sprintf('%.15f', $a)."<br>";
echo "First : $t<br>";
$t = preg_replace('/0+$/','',$t);
echo "Second : $t <br>";
```

This gives output as
First : 0.800000000000000
Second : 0.800000000000000

Could you help me to find out why the last 0s are not replaced by regular expression in this case as the expected output is 0.8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your variable `$t` contains `0.800000000000000<br>` so there ar no trailing zeros to cut off.

you'll have to shorten the string before appending `<br>`.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are adding `<br>` to the end of `$t` with this line:

```
$t = sprintf('%.15f', $a)."<br>";
```

You regex no longer matches trailing 0. `"<br>"` is part of the presentation, you should add it at the very end.

Comment: oh! Sorry, I could not notice this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You append a `<br>` tag at the end, while the Regex says 0's before end of line

```
'/0+$/'
    ^ <- end of line, nothing should come after 0's
".800000000000000"

$a = .80;
$t = sprintf('%.15f', $a)."<br>";
// $t = .800000000000000<br>
```